# Para que sirve QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE y QT_END_NAMESPACE

Tags: c++, qt

Estudiando los ejemplos incluidos en Qt-5.9.1 me encuentro con el siguiente código que no puedo comprender:

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QAction;
class QMenu;
class QPlainTextEdit;
class QSessionManager;
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{ ... }
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cual es su función a la hora de crear una clase?

Answer (score 0):

Qt puede configurarse para que use o no espacios de nombres. ¿Para qué?

Imagínate (por poner el primer ejemplo que se me ocurre) que estais migrando una aplicación de una versión de Qt a otra y en medio del cambio surge la necesidad de sacar una versión de la aplicación... teniendo cada versión de Qt en un espacio de nombres diferente puedes evitar que los nombres colisionen.

Lo normal es que Qt no se monte en un espacio de nombres, pero aun así estas macros te permitirán escribir código que funcione bien en cualquier situación sin tener que editarlo posteriormente.